# SQL statement - difficulty producing two fields from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am relatively new to SQL and able to write some simple statements with some JOIN, WHERE thrown in. I also have some experience with SSRS 2008. However I am having difficulty producing two (unique) lists of names based on one table.

I am trying to produce a report containing Staff Members which lists Clients they look after. All names (regardless whether Staff or Client) are held in the Person table. I can run a simple query listing all staff members or clients but I am unable to list both.

To produce the Client list my query would be simply

```
SELECT p.Forenames, p.Surname
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN Client AS c ON p.ID = c.ID
```

and to produce the Staff list my query would be as above but the INNER JOIN as follows:

```
INNER JOIN StaffMember AS s ON p.ID = s.ID
```

The link between Staff Member and Client with all the different links are as follows (for reference).

```
Client.ID = ClientRecordForm.Client_ID
Person.ID = ClientRecordForm.AssignedSupportWorker_ID
Person.ID = StaffMember.ID
StaffMember.ID = ClientRecordForm.AssignedSupportWorker_ID
```

To help illustrate this, I can run a query to list Staff Members who have been assigned to Clients.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Forenames, p.Surname
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN ClientRecordForm AS crf ON p.ID = crf.AssignedSupportWorker_ID
```

This last query is essentially what I want but I am struggling to add the Client names as I don't seem to be able to distinguish the Clients as I am already using the Person table

Comment: It would help if you edited the question and provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: Perhaps you don't know that you can join more than 2 tables? You can join on Client.ID = ClientRecordForm.Client_ID to get client data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show persons and be able to distinguish clients as well, try a self join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Forenames, p.Surname
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN ClientRecordForm AS crf ON p.ID = crf.AssignedSupportWorker_ID
inner join person as personClients on crf.clientid = personClients.id
```

As you can see, you could then join another persons table to get `StaffMember`, you can join from `personClients` to `Client` to get information there ...etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I get a list of clients with corresponding staff member next to them. I didnt realise you can essentially "clone" the person table.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Forenames, p.Surname
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN ClientRecordForm AS crf 
    ON p.ID = crf.AssignedSupportWorker_ID
INNER JOIN Client AS c
    ON c.ID = crf.Client_ID
```